# 1970's Gitane please help identify the model

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

Does anyone know the model of this bike?  Where do I look on the bike to find out?

[image]

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know the model of this bike? Where do I look on the bike to find out?

There are catalogs for Gitane but it does not appear to be one catalog for each year.

- [Velo Pages 1970 - 1974](http://www.velo-pages.com/main.php?g2_itemId=1659) (Did they only have one catalog for four years? Seems unlikely but I can't find any other U.S. catalogs)
- [Gitane USA](http://www.gitaneusa.com/catalogues01.asp)

From what I can see it's about a [1970 Gran Sport](http://www.velo-pages.com/main.php?g2_itemId=1693&g2_imageViewsIndex=1) in sport orange. Your bike has a different quick release on the front than the rear. From what I'm seeing in the catalogs the rear is original and the front is off some other bike.
In 1970 they had Mafac brakes like yours has. Sometime after 1970 they went to Weinmann.
[image]

Other Information on the Gran Sport

- [Gitane USA](http://www.gitaneusa.com/models_5.asp)

> The “Grand Sport DeLuxe” came in both men’s and women’s models. An entry level bicycle, they were used mainly for commuting and were extremely popular with students due to their affordability. The name was used by Gitane throughout the 1970's, but was not used in the 1980's for reasons unknown.
>
> Grand Sport DeLuxe’s can be identified by their stamped dropouts and fake chrome fork crown. They also include kick stand mounts, which did not come with Interclubs or any of the other higher-end Gitane bicycles. Because of their popularity, they are the most readily available of all Gitane models today and can be found regular on internet auction sites.

- [Classic Rendesvous](http://classicrendezvous.com/France/bicycles/Gitane/gallery.htm)

> The Interclub and Gran Sport DeLuxe were the bottom level Gitanes offered during the early 1970s, and don’t warrant much space here or in your collection. They do, however, make for great “city bike” converts. Stamped steel dropouts and “chromoly” tubing, they came with extremely heavy Stronglight steel cranksets and usually with Simplex derailleurs and Mafac Racer brakes. With a similar look to the Super Corsa and TdF, they can still look good, even if they weren’t the fastest bikes on the road!

Answer (score 1):

Yep, except for the kick stand, it's exactly like my Gitane Interclub, same color, other trim details. I bought it new in 1972 in Bowling Green Ohio. Still have and ride it in rural Georgia although I used it in Atlanta for a few years in the late 70's. It's 50 years old this year. Still a nice ride. Very pretty. Get nice comments when I'm on the road! lol-